# WooCommerce Grid / List view

Tags: list, plugins, views

Is there any experience with Woocommerce Grid / List view plugin, I set to automatically start the list view but the problem is that while the page is loading initially opens a grid view and instantly change to list view, it takes 1 second but it seems confusing.Is there any idea how it could be resolved?

I took the code from the following [link](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-woocommerce-grid-list-toggle-make-list-view-default-instead-of-grid)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('ul.products').addClass('list');
});
```

Comment: Where did you place that code? Do you get any JS errors?

Comment: At the and of file:  `assets > js > jquery.gridlistview.min.js` ,  
and is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undo any changes you've have made to the file, then add this **at the top**:

```
if ( jQuery.cookie( "gridcookie" ) != "grid" ) {
    jQuery.cookie( "gridcookie", "list", { path: "/" } );
}
```

**Update:** Sounds like a [FOUC](http://www.bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp/). Let's take a different approach - remove the code you added above & try adding the following to your theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'wpse_71885_shop_loop_list_init' );

function wpse_71885_shop_loop_list_init() {
    ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( "ul.products" ).addClass( jQuery.cookie( "gridcookie" ) || "list" );
</script>

<?php
}
```

This will add the grid/list class to the product list *immediately* after it enters the document (as opposed to waiting for document ready).

Comment: I enter the code as you told me, but still the same problem appears

Comment: Try my second solution instead.